# Generate Insert statements for result set in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, resultset

Is there a tool for oracle that will generate insert statements for the resultset? I am using Oracle SQL developer if it makes any difference.

For example, for a query of a table `select * from t1 where this = 'that'`

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a1      a2      a3
b1      b2      b3
```

I want to export the resultset to

```
INSERT INTO T1 (Col1, Col2, Col3) values ('a1', 'a2', 'a3');
INSERT INTO T1 (Col1, Col2, Col3) values ('b1', 'b2', 'b3');
```

Comment: You're question is a bit vague but have you looked into SQL*Loader?

Comment: Right now I have to export the entire table and select the insert statements I want and send it to my co-worker. The table name and structure is the same. I have to do this for multiple tables everyday. There has to be a better way to create selective `insert statements`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your query in SQL Developer.

In the result grid, right click. Select Export...

A popup dialog is presented asking for how to export the result. The default is insert. You can select a file to save to, or copy to clipboard, or various other options.

This is on SQL Developer 3.0.4.

Comment: Pl/SQL Developer v12.0.7 does not give any such options other than to dump the file out. There is no possibility to create INSERT statements.

Comment: It does for me, at least v13 and v14. I'm pretty sure it was there in v12 as well.

Answer (score -2):

With export you can do something like:

```
exp userid=user/passwd tables=t1 query="""where this = 'that'"""
```